# How to remove a volume in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I'm experiencing the same problem as found here:
[mkdir .ssh in a Dockerfile, folder is not there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40097246/mkdir-ssh-in-a-dockerfile-folder-is-not-there)

I'm wondering if there is a way for my dockerfile to remove a volume declared by its parent?

My reasoning for this is that; the volume was declared to mount to an external database, the image I'm creating is for testing purposes and contains the data present for the volume internally.  Ideally I don't want to have to populate this in my entry point as it's an expensive operation.

Comment: can you share docker file? Customise the base dockerimage and create your own by adding RUN rm -rf /path/of/folder in docker file.

Answer (score 2):

See also [How to remove configure volumes in docker images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39588984/)

Actually I did have a very similar use case in using an image from production that would be modified for testing. The only chance is to modify the metadata of the parent image. As I need to that regulary, I have created a little script for that, have a look at [docker-copyedit](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-copyedit) if that can help you.